# Select from difiirents fields models Methode odoo8

Tags: odoo

Can I select some data fields from different models and display these fields in my tree view, then I modify my selection and persist in other models?

`'@api.v8
def get_data(self):
    data = self.env['my.models]].browse(id)'`

Comment: What you want? Are addition of data or some data fields?

Comment: select data from my data base and display its in tree view

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways to provide selection list values that is accepted by OpenERP:

1. Specifying directly in the field.selection definition: 'field_1':
   fields.selection([('value1', 'String 1'), ('value2', 'String 2')],
   'Field Label')
2. Specifying using a name list variable outside of the field.selection
   definition: 'field_1': fields.selection(LIST_VARIABLE, 'Field
   Label').  Where LIST_VARIABLE is defined beforehand: LIST_VARIABLE =
   [('value1', 'String 1'), ('value2', 'String 2')]
3. Specifying using a method: 'field_1': fields.selection(_method_name,
   'Field Label').  Where _method_name is defined beforehand:

   def _method_name(self, cr, uid, context=None):

   return [('value1', 'String 1'), ('value2', 'String 2')]

Now, you need to check first which one is your current selection field is.  If it is using method No. 1, then you need to redefine it to use either method No 2 or method No 3.  If it is using method No. 2 or 3, you just need to change either the variable (you can use LIST_VARIABLE.append(('value3', 'String 3'))) to return the new value.